# How to rescrew a pull up bar

Tags: mechanisms, coupling, frame, tubing

Is there a way to fix a pull up bar when the tip screwed right off and won't screw on again?

The thread hole hits the screw (detail) and just clunks there, spinning round and round without latching.

[image: pull up bar where tip has unscrewed loose]

Comment: If there is no need for length adjustment, weld the pieces together. I would try Teflon tape first to see if it works just fine.

Comment: is the thread stripped, does it just not start, or is the threaded rod inside the tube spinning freely?

Comment: r13
It won't go in more than the tip, I'd need to cut it, was looking for a nondestructive solution.